# how to set the before property of css according to the component that is getting rendered in switch case

Tags: reactjs

this is the switch case which is rendering the component in ui

```
     var {route="dashboard"}= main
 var returnComponent = ""
 switch(route){
   case "dashboard" : 
   returnComponent= <DashBoard/> 
   break;
   case "task" : 
   returnComponent= <Task/> 
   break;
   case "project" : 
   returnComponent= <Project/>
   break;
   case "tasklibrary" : 
   returnComponent= <TaskLibrary/>
   break;
   default: 
   returnComponent= <DashBoard/>
 }
```

this is where it is getting rendered

```
<div className="flex-one main-content-box" style={{height:'calc(100% - 55px)'}}>
         {returnComponent}
        </div>
```

the css of the class main-content-box has got before attribute in css.....
where the top property should be be changing according to the component that is rendered

```
.main-content-box:before {
    content: "";
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    border-right: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    position: absolute;
    top: 136px;
    left: -6px;
    /* right: 87px; */
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    z-index: 2;
    transform: rotate(
223deg);
}
```

so how to change the top property of the pseudo class according to the component that is getting rendered for example if the dashboard component is getting rendered then the top property of main-content-box will be 30px and if the task compoenent is rendered the same top property will be 130px

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Using CSS variable

One approach is assigning which component to render, you may also assign the desired `top` value

```js
var { route = "dashboard" } = main;
var returnComponent = "";

// top value for the ::before element
let top = '136px';

switch (route) {
  case "dashboard":
    returnComponent = <DashBoard />;
    top = '30px';
    break;
  case "task":
    returnComponent = <Task />;
    top = '130px';
    break;
  case "project":
    returnComponent = <Project />;
    break;
  case "tasklibrary":
    returnComponent = <TaskLibrary />;
    break;
  default:
    returnComponent = <DashBoard />;
}
```

After that, you can use the `top` value in the `style` object and assign it to a css variable such as `--top`

```html
<div className="flex-one main-content-box" style={{ '--top': top, height: 'calc(100% - 55px)' }}>
  {returnComponent}
</div>
```

Then finally, you can use the variable in your css code

```css
.main-content-box:before {
    content: "";
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    border-right: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    position: absolute;
    
    /* use the --top variable */
    top: var(--top, 136px);

    left: -6px;
    /* right: 87px; */
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    z-index: 2;
    transform: rotate(223deg);
}
```

This works for one attribute differentiation. If there're a lot of differences among different elements. You should use the class approach as Summer suggested.

---

### Using class

You may also append the `route` in the `className` of the container.

```html
<div className={`flex-one main-content-box ${route}`} style={{ height: 'calc(100% - 55px)' }}>
  {returnComponent}
</div>
```

Then in your css file, you can add other rules to change the `top` value accordingly:

```css
.main-content-box:before {
    content: "";
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    border-right: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    position: absolute;
    top: 136px;
    left: -6px;
    /* right: 87px; */
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    z-index: 2;
    transform: rotate(223deg);
}

/* changing the top according to different route */
.main-content-box.dashboard:before {
    top: 30px;
}

.main-content-box.task:before {
    top: 130px;
}
```

Comment: can you explain me the second approach

Comment: I've added the details of the second approach.

Comment: I like this route as className solution! It's definitely much neater than mine and involves less code. Normally I'd be slightly concerned about the tight coupling, but it's already very tightly coupled anyway.

Comment: @Summer I think so too. But the class may resolve unpredicted. It would be a disaster if a route is called `button` or `hidden` and just so happen it has other unwanted rules attached to it. If that's the case it’s safer to use attributes such as `data-route`

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there are much cleaner ways of doing this, but for now you can simply make a `class` variable that you assign during the switch statement, and append it to your parent component like so:

```js
<div 
  className={`flex-one main-content-box ${class}`} 
  style={{height:'calc(100% - 55px)'}}
>
  {returnComponent}
</div>
```

Additionally, never use inline `style` props. They cause a lot of unnecessary rerenders. Put it in your normal css.

Comment: assign class variable in switch statement dint get you. can you please show me where you are asking me to do that

Comment: @AbhishekRoy In the same way you assign `returnComponent`, make another var called `class` and assign it a string like `top-dashboard`. Then add `.top-dashboard` to your css and set the top property to 30px. And so on.

Comment: for that i have to make different class for different component

Comment: @AbhishekRoy Yes. Naturally. There are cleaner ways of doing this entire thing, but in the end if vanilla CSS is your styling solution, you **have** to use different class names for different styles. Inline styling degrades DOM performance by itself, but it's even worse when used in React.